# Magento not show modules in admin/configuration/advance

Tags: magento-1.7

I will make module properly
in apps/code/local/....
and make config.xml in etc folder..
and packegname_modulename.xml in apps/etc/models..
every thing is proper but it not showing the module in admin/configuration/advance

Whats the problem....

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: have you cleared the cache ? (all cache) The "disable_local_module" in your local.xml file is set to false ? (app/etc/local.xml)

Comment: @dagfr thanx man i am new in magento i have little problem in Eav also my Setup Resource installer script is not working .i dont know whats the problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your file at app/etc/modules/packegname_modulename.xml is in the correct format.. It has to be as below.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Packegname_Modulename>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Packegname_Modulename>
    </modules>
</config>
```

There shouldnt be any unnecessary spaces between the codePool tag. codePool tag has to be in this format only as `<codePool>`. If you are creating the module under local folder then codePool as to be `local` if in `community` then the codePool has to be `community` instead of `local`